# Entity Framework Change Tracker

Tags: system.reactive, entity-framework-6

Isn't there anything in EF6 ChangeTracker that could be observed to create an event when HasChanges has been changed?

Basic use for this is to turn on the SAVE button on a view model, when the context registers a change.

Comment: Are you saying that if another user changes the record that you are working on, that you'd like the HasChanged to know about that and fire an event?

Comment: No, I would like an event every time the context changetracker haschanges property changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This feels wrong to me. Your view should be informing your view-model of changes (typically by binding the view to view-models implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged`). Then your view-model can expose the need to save directly without reaching into your data layer. Libraries like `ReactiveUI` can help make this easy.

However, if you want to be evil (yes I'm opinionated on this point!) you *could* check it on a timer. The only reason I can think of for doing this is because you are sharing your context across views - but it's still a pretty bad reason:

```
var hasChanges = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.5))
                          .Select(_ => DbChangeTracker.HasChanges);

hasChanges.ObserveOnDispatcher.Subscribe(i => /* logic to set save button state */);
```

If you go down this route, you'd also want to check `DbChangeTracker.HasChanges` imperatively before exiting your view to avoid losing unsaved changes.

Comment: At this point, I'm agreeing with you - cause I don't believe in the polling however light weight.  However, I'm curious as to why the EF team didn't think to associate an event with the HasChanges property.  If the VM design holds absolutely, then the HasChanges property is not required as well, as the VM would always know when a property was changed.  Still, since it's open sourced, perhaps somebody (yes I'm looking into it) might want to hook up an event when the setter gets invoked? Who on the EF team can we get an option on this?